# How to decode this error when using Raspberry Pi to send an image to a QL-800 printer in Python?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, printers, raspberry-pi-zero

Everything installed fine to get the Raspberry Pi version of the brother printer driver.  I used
https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=lpql800eus and I used https://pypi.org/project/brother-ql/

Using the traceback, how can I understand what value I should use for the variable "printer"?  I think that is the issue.

Here is the code:

```
import pygame
from PIL import Image
from brother_ql.conversion import convert
from brother_ql.backends.helpers import send
from brother_ql.raster import BrotherQLRaster
#####################################################################################################
### Test QR-800 Printer
#####################################################################################################
im = Image.open('QLtest.png')
im.resize((306, 991)) 

backend = 'pyusb'    # 'pyusb', 'linux_kernal', 'network'
model = 'QL-800' # your printer model.

# HERE IS WHERE THE PROBLEM HAPPENS
# The code said to use a value from the Windows usb driver filter of 'usb://0x04f9:0x209b'
# or if have a Raspberry Pi Zero, to use for Linux/Raspberry Pi '/dev/usb/lp0'.
# So I tried with '/dev/usb/lp0' but get error
printer = '/dev/usb/lp0'    

qlr = BrotherQLRaster(model)
qlr.exception_on_warning = True
instructions = convert(
    qlr=qlr, 
    images=[im],    #  Takes a list of file names or PIL objects.
    label='29x90', 
    rotate='90',    # 'Auto', '0', '90', '270'
    threshold=70.0,    # Black and white threshold in percent.
    dither=False, 
    compress=False, 
    red=False,    # Only True if using Red/Black 62 mm label tape.
    dpi_600=False, 
    lq=False,    # True for low quality.
    no_cut=False
)
send(instructions=instructions, printer_identifier=printer, backend_identifier=backend, blocking=True)
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_printer.py", line 36, in <module>
    send(instructions=instructions, printer_identifier=printer, backend_identifier=backend, blocking=True)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/brother_ql/backends/helpers.py", line 57, in send
    printer = BrotherQLBackend(printer_identifier)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/brother_ql/backends/pyusb.py", line 79, in __init__
    vendor, product = int(vendor, 16), int(product, 16)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: ''
```

Comment: Try switching the backend to 'linux_kernal' or leave it empty.

Comment: Thank you Mike67 for trying to help me.  I tried using "linux_kernal" and got a new error saying "Backend linux_kernal not implemented".

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_printer.py", line 36, in <module>
    send(instructions=instructions, printer_identifier=printer, backend_identifier=backend, blocking=True)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/brother_ql/backends/helpers.py", line 53, in send
    be = backend_factory(selected_backend)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/brother_ql/backends/__init__.py", line 38, in backend_factory
    raise NotImplementedError('Backend %s not implemented.' % backend_name)
NotImplementedError: Backend linux_kernal not implemented.

Comment: Sorry - Typo on my part. Try `linux_kernel`.

Comment: God Bless You Mike67,  I am one step closer. Different error.  The message is now:  'printing completed' status not received.' and 'waiting to receive' status not received.   And also the red link is blinking on the printer.  Any ideas what what I should do next?

Comment: I also tried changing the printer to "Editor Lite" mode and, running the same code, this time I got "No such file or directory: '/dev/usb/lp0'.

Comment: I LOVE STACK OVERFLOW and the people so much.  THANK YOU Mike67.  You got the code talking to the printer so then I noticed the label paper I was using did not match what the python code had programmed.  So I changed paper type and it worked.  Ok, I just now got to figure out what python wants to call DK-2251 type of paper and it should be solid.  I cannot tell you how excited I am after 4 days of struggle.  I will give another update once I have it perfect.

Comment: Different error --> different question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(moving comment to answer)

In your code, you are specifying the printer path as `/dev/usb/lp0` but specifying the backend as `pyusb`. For USB, the library expects a path like 'usb://0x04f9:0x209b' which caused the error you see. The path you have (/dev/usb/lp0) indicates a **linux_kernel** backend. Try updating your code accordingly.

```
backend = 'linux_kernel'
```

The **brother_ql** library can also guess the backend based on the path format.

You can view the module source here:

[https://github.com/pklaus/brother_ql/blob/142cf744d89a912df729bbf15d35468d780559df/brother_ql/backends/**init**.py](https://github.com/pklaus/brother_ql/blob/142cf744d89a912df729bbf15d35468d780559df/brother_ql/backends/__init__.py)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone.
What made it work was using linux_kernel (instead of linux_kernal which was a typo).

HERE IS SAMPLE CODE WHICH WORKS FOR QL-800 PRINTER

```
import pygame
import time
from PIL import Image
from brother_ql.conversion import convert
from brother_ql.backends.helpers import send
from brother_ql.raster import BrotherQLRaster
#####################################################################################################
### Test QR-800 Printer
#####################################################################################################
QLtest = pygame.image.load('red_black313x156.png')
QLtest = pygame.transform.scale(QLtest,(1044,696)) 
pygame.image.save(QLtest,'RedBlack2_1044x696.png') 

# You will need to convert to PIL object or save to harddrive with pygame.image.save and read back.
# For the Red lable, you need to resize in pygame to AnyWidthx696.  Premium Kiosk uses 1044,696.
image = Image.open('RedBlack2_1044x696.png')

backend = 'linux_kernel'    # 'pyusb', 'linux_kernel', 'network'
model = 'QL-800' # your printer model.

# The author of the code said to use a value from the Windows usb driver filter of 'usb://0x04f9:0x209b'
# or if have a Raspberry Pi Zero, to use for Linux/Raspberry Pi '/dev/usb/lp0'.
printer = '/dev/usb/lp0'    

qlr = BrotherQLRaster(model)
qlr.exception_on_warning = True
'''
To make it work for different types of labels, you need to change the label parameter below.  Here are some examples:
For the 29mm x 90.3mm, use label = '29x90' and red=False and (306, 991) image
For the DK-2251 Black/Red badge, use label='62red' and red=True and (AnyWidth,696) image (note, Premium Kiosk are 1044,696) 
note, if you don't have red or black in your image, you will not see anything for the red/black labels.
To learn more or to use other labels, run these commands in the command line:
     export PATH="${PATH}:~/.local/bin" (just always need to do this first to reach brother_ql)
     brother_ql_create --help (to understand the options in the code below)
     brother_ql_info list-label-sizes (to tell python what label (called Name) and image size (called Printable px)
'''
badge = convert(
    qlr=qlr, 
    images=[image],    #  Takes a list of file names or PIL objects.
    label='62red', 
    rotate='90',    # 'Auto', '0', '90', '270'
    threshold=70.0,    # Black and white threshold in percent.
    dither=False, 
    compress=False, 
    red=True,    # Only True if using Red/Black 62 mm label tape.
    dpi_600=False, 
    lq=False,    # True for low quality.
    no_cut=False
)
send(instructions=badge, printer_identifier=printer, backend_identifier=backend, blocking=True)
```